# Trying to get an average in mySQL in Wordpress with PHP, object returns as an array, need it as a string

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a custom table in my wordpress install, and I want to get an average out of a column on the table.  I'm using the following PHP:

```
 $latavg = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT AVG(stop_lat) FROM stops_txt");
```

However, when I want to use the average later on as a string, it returns as 'ARRAY', yet attempting to use PRINT_R to view the array reveals nothing.  The Column in the table is a DECIMAL data-type, what am I missing?

Comment: then just use `$array['stop_lat']` ...

Comment: `AVG(stop_lat)` can be fetch in PHP as `$row['AVG(stop_lat)']` not like @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs said.. More easy is to use a alias in the SQL `AVG(stop_lat) AS stop_lat` then you can use `$row['stop_lat']` in PHP

Comment: @RaymondNijland wait, `AVG` is not a mysql function and a field name? Or does the use of functions still carry on over as key name in returned data?

Comment: "Or does the use of functions still carry on over as key name in returned data?" @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs yes it does .. If you use `SELECT AVG(column) ...` it's basiclly `SELECT AVG(column) AS 'AVG(column)'` more or less check this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fkZ7Eib2DsMcWV4mLN7wR/0 .. notice the rewrite `/* select#1 */ select avg(1) AS AVG(1)`

Comment: @RaymondNijland ah.. didn't know that. Never really used MYSQL functions, pref. to handle via PHP (as in `count()` vs `SELECT COUNT(*)`) - feels like a bad design, but I wouldn't know to much about that sorta thing

Comment: @RaymondNijland I work daily with tables xD I just mean, I'd prefer if PDO returned column_name rather than function(column_name) as the array key

Comment: Never mind i geuss i misreaded and misunderstood that other comment the first time.. i understood you have a preference using PHP `count()` of MySQL's `COUNT(*)` to count records @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs

Comment: @RaymondNijland ahh I see, I mean, I still kinda do have that pref. but not bad design to use COUNT(*) over count($data) - I'm just way way better at PHP then I am MYSQL so I just stick to what I know (probably next step to being a better dev is learn MYSQL more ... extensively (not sure if thats the right word here but.. going with it xD))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you just want a single variable instead of a whole row or column in `wpdb`, use `get_var()` instead:

```
$latavg = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT AVG(stop_lat) FROM stops_txt");
```

[Here is the complete `wpdb` reference.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Variable)